# Unable to connect to mongo DB with Grails 3.1.1

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I'm creating an application from scratch and when I start the application, I get the following error. My MongoDB version is 2.6.1

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.notNull(Assertions.java:37) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.<init>(MongoCredential.java:233) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createCredential(MongoCredential.java:106) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoClientFactoryBean.java:145) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

My DataSource Config is as follows

```
grails {
            mongodb {
                host = "localhost"
                port = 27017
                username = "admin"
                password = "password"
                databaseName = "sta"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [official guide](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html):

> If you want to configure how Grails connects to MongoDB then you can do so using the following settings in grails-app/conf/application.yml:
>
> ```
> grails:
>     mongodb:
>         host: "localhost"
>         port: 27017
>         username: "blah"
>         password: "blah"
>         databaseName: "foo"
> ```

Check also next chapter: **2.3 Advanced Configuration**.

Comment: You can do it either in yml file or application.groovy. I prefer the .groovy file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both .yml file and the .groovy file. I also  created a new sample but it didn't work. The issue was the plugin which was being shipped with version 3.1.1. Once I upgraded to 3.1.3, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in the GORM plugin.  It doesn't seem to recognize the databaseName property.  It does seem to work if you use the connections string.

connectionString: "mongodb://username:password@host:port/databaseName"

For details:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/